# How do I track a pop up in Google Analytics / Tag Manager or Custom JS script

Tags: google-analytics

We've just overhauled our registration process on our site. 
When a user registers they are directed to a pop up / light box as opposed to a unique url.

Tracking the conversion funnel was super easy until this change, as goals where assigned through the various entrance and exist points.

Is it possible to somehow track say for example, how many times the light box was closed (ie user does not want to register), or how long the user was on the lightbox? I imagine this would be a case of custom .js script?

Essentially I need this info to pull into Google Analytics. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To track the conversion funnel, with a lightbox, it would be better to use virtual pageviews. ([in Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) or in [Google Tag Manager](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/09/10/fire-virtual-pageview-google-tag-manager/)). Then you can add the virtual URLS to a conversion funnel and track user behaviour and abandonment.

Closing the lightbox should be an event or a return to the real URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You can use jQuery to track the click on the button

```
jQuery( function() {
     jQuery('#button1').click( function() {
          // Use google tracking code here. Use Events
     });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you show what the event code looks like?